# Write dictionary data to file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary that when saved to a file outputs this:

```
Score,5
Name, Lenard
```

I would like the output to be in the format of

```
Name Score
Student 10
```

How would I do this? and how would I also read the data written to the file and sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, although it would have been nice to see what you have already tried:

Define some data in your python file

```
scores = [
        {'name': 'Lenard', 'score': 5 },
        {'name': 'Tim', 'score': 10}
        ]

file = 'students.txt'
```

Write a function to populate the file with data

```
def writefile():
    fil = open(file, 'w')       # open file
    fil.truncate()              # truncate the contents of the file
    fil.write("Name\tScore")    # write heading
    for score in scores:        # write each record
        fil.write("\n%s\t%s" % (score['name'], score['score']))
    fil.close()                 # close file
```

Write a function to read the file

```
def readfile():
    with open(file) as fil:     # open file
        scores = fil.read().splitlines() # split file contents by lines

    count = 0
    for score in scores:        # loop through all lines
        if count == 0:          # skip first line
            count = count + 1
            continue
        data = score.split()    # split line by space
        print ("%s\t%s" % (data[0], data[1])) # print name and score
```

Call your functions

```
writefile() # write file with scores
print ('file written\n----')
print ('read file and print contents below')
readfile()  # read file with score
```

Result:

```
$ /c/Python34/python.exe test.py
file written
----
read file and print contents below
Lenard  5
Tim     10
```

Your file will look like this (data is separated by tabs):

```
  Name    Score
  Lenard  5
  Tim 10
```

You can use some of the keywords used above and find better methods of creating your program. Note that `scores` variable is a list of dicts.